# If $\int_0^\theta g(t)dt=0$ for all $\theta$, $g$ measurable, is $g$ zero almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $g$ is **only measurable** (not necessarily continuous), and that for all $\theta>0$, $\int_0^\theta g(t)dt=0$. Does that imply that $g$ is (almost everywhere) identically zero?

If $g$ were continuous, we could say that $g$ must be of constant sign on some interval, in which case it has to be zero on that interval. But if it's only measurable?

Comment: Take a function that equals $\;1\;$ at some point $\;>0\;$ and zero everywhere else. Then its integral for *any* $\;\theta>0\;$ is zero but the function is not the zero one...Continuity is important here.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I should have said this explicitly, but as usual in Lebesgue-land, when I said "identically zero", I meant "zero almost everywhere". Does that change things?

Comment: Come to think of it, since our condition implies that $\int g=0$ on any interval, does that then imply that $\int g=0$ on any measurable set, which we can then apply to the sets on which $g\geq 0$ and $g\leq 0$, implying that $g$ is either zero a.e. on these, or that those sets of measure zero?

Comment: The canonical approach is to consider the collection C of Borel subsets of [0,+oo) such that the integral of g on B is zero. If you can show every Borel set is in C, you are done... So, which B are in C?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are integrating $g$, we can safely assume that $g\in L^1_{loc}$.
Then, the function $f(\theta) := \int_0^\theta g(t)\, dt = 0$ for every $\theta$. 
Since $f$ is (locally) absolutely continuous, $0 = f'(\theta) = g(\theta)$ for almost every $\theta$, hence we can conclude that $g(\theta) = 0$ almost everywhere.